# How to solve this question

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

prove that if $R\leq S$ and $S\leq N$ then $P(N,S)$ is divisible by $P(N,R)$

Let $s = r +k$ since s is greater than r by some value but we don’t we don’t how much so I used k

$\frac{n!}{(n-(r+k))!}$/$\frac{n}{n-r}!$

$\frac{n!}{(n-r-k))!}$/$\frac{n}{n-r}!$ where you can cancel out n!

I am not getting how to solve farther than this.

Now , I also don’t the meaning behind this question . Because $r$ can be just any value. There may be many values of  $P(N,S)$  divisible by $P(N,R)$. Many different values for $N , R$ and $S$. so , from this way of solving . Can we find at least which value is $n,r$ and $s$ also. Because i think just by dividing variables , how can I find the real values when they are just not given.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are so close to the solution. As you suggested let

$$
s=r+k
\\n=s+m=r+k+m
$$

where $k\ge0$ and $m\ge0$. Then

$$
\frac{P(N,S)}{P(N,R)}=\frac{n!}{(n-s)!}\frac{(n-r)!}{n!}=\frac{(k+m)!}{m!}=(m+1)(m+2)...(m+k)
$$

if $k=0$, then the division becomes 1.

Comment: Why assume k = 1? Why not for m ?

Comment: I am not assuming $k=1$, $k\ge0$ (I just stated the division of the result for k=0).  However, P(N,S) is always divisible by P(N,R) given the condition $N\ge S\ge R$ and the result of the division depends on k and m.

Comment: I meant to write why assume k =0.actually. Why only stated the result of division for k =0. Does that on,y prove the answer ? Why not other situations

Comment: oh ok, I have stated $k=0$ specifically since in my answer I have written $\frac{(k+m)!}{m!}=(m+1)(m+2)...(m+k)$ where $(m+1)(m+2)...(m+k)$ doesn't include the case for $k=0$. If $k=1$, then the answer is $m+1$, if $k=2$, the answer is $(m+1)(m+2)$ and so on. That is why I specifically stated the result for the division for the case $k=0$ which is 1.

Comment: thanks I got it .

Answer (score -1):

Start by proving that the quotient
$\frac{P(n,s)}{P(n,r)}$
is indeed an integer.

Comment: Ok but what’s the reason for that ?